# I keep getting Error: Could not find or load main class and cant figure out why?

Tags: java

I am extremely brand new at coding and trying to teach myself some tricks, but they arent working. Here is my code, someone told me that my braces may be wrong but I cant understand why it wont compile. I keep getting the Error:Could not find or load main class. Perhaps I am accessing it incorrectly? Thank you in advance for helping me learn how to do this correctly.

```
public class Point3D {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    public Point3D (int xAxis, int yAxis, int zAxis) {
    }
    public int getxAxis (int x) {
        return x;
    }
    public int getyAxis (int y) {
        return y;
    }
    public int getzAxis (int z) {
        return z;
    }
    public void setx(int xAxis){
        this.x = xAxis;
    }
    public void sety(int yAxis){
        this.y = yAxis;
    }
    public void setz(int zAxis){
        this.z = zAxis;
    }
    public int getDistanceToOrigin (int x, int y, int z, int x1, int y1, int z1) {
        return getDistanceToOrigin = ((int x1-int x); (int y1-int y); (int z1-int z));
    }
    public int getDistance (int x, int y, int z, int x1, int y1, int z1) {
        return getDistance = ((5 - int x); (7 - int y); (9-int z));
    }

    public void howFar (){
        System.out.println ("Your original point is at: " 
                 +Point3D +"and is: " +getDistanceToOrigin +" away from the "
                 + "origin of 0, 0, 0");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point3D location = new Point3D();
            location.setx(3);
            location.sety(2);
            location.setz(1);
            location.getDistance();
            location.howFar();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have many mistakes in code. For example `Point3D location = new Point3D();`.
But you haven't constructor with empty arguments, like
`public Point3D () {} `

Other 
`return getDistance = ((5 - int x); (7 - int y); (9-int z));`

Comment: (int x1-int x); (int y1-int y); (int z1-int z)); what are trying to do with this

Comment: You can use sdk (eclipse, netbeans, idea) to find mistakes in your java code.

Comment: Are you compiling or running the program

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to return? Because you current code tries to return the difference in x, y and z and not the difference from one point to another. Also `return getDistanceToOrigin = ((int x1-int x); (int y1-int y); (int z1-int z));` will not work as you are trying to return 3 results but you started you method with `public int` and that means that only one argument can be returned. To solve this you could try using an array. Also you call your method `getDistance` without arguments while 6 are needed. And you use Point3D in your `howFar` method without saying what Point3D is.

Answer (score 1):

Mistakes

1.make your variables private if you are accessing them from getter/setters.

```
public int x;
public int y;
public int z;
```

2. Default constructors

   `Point3D location = new Point3D();`
    this will make a call to the default constructor but in your case there is none.
    This will also create an error. Either create a default constructor or make objects like
   `Point3D location = new Point3D(1,2,3);`
3. Mistake 3(Dont know what are yr trying to do here )

   `public int getDistanceToOrigin (int x, int y, int z, int x1, int y1, int z1) {`

   ```
       return getDistanceToOrigin = ((int x1-int x); (int y1-int y); (int z1-int z));
   }
   public int getDistance (int x, int y, int z, int x1, int y1, int z1) {
       return getDistance = ((5 - int x); (7 - int y); (9-int z));
   }
   ```

`return getDistanceToOrigin = ((int x1-int x); (int y1-int y); (int z1-int z));`
A return statement can return only one thing, it cannot have `;` in between
it will return only one interger value, if you want to return two or more numbers then you may have to return an array of numbers.

Comment: `public int getDistanceToOrigin (int x, int y, int z, int x1, int y1, int z1) {
        return getDistanceToOrigin = ((int x1-int x); (int y1-int y); (int z1-int z));
    }`
May be it means:
`public Point3D getDistanceToOrigin (int x, int y, int z, int x1, int y1, int z1) {
        return new Point3D(x1-x, y1 - y, z1-z);
    }`

Comment: the return type states that its an integer value, but ya you might be right.